# Ant fails in try catch block

Tags: java, ant, try-catch, ant-contrib

In my ANT build I have the following code:

```
<trycatch reference="exception_ref">
    <try>
        <echo>Start Building Delivery</echo>
    </try>
    <catch>
        <property name="exception" refid="exception_ref" />
        <property name="message" value="Error in trycatch block:${line.separator}${exception}" />
        <echo message="${message}" />
        <fail message="${message}" />
    </catch>
    <finally>
        <echo>Finally</echo>
    </finally>
</trycatch>
```

Ant says:

> Problem: failed to create task or type trycatch
>   Cause: The name is undefined.
>   Action: Check the spelling.
>   Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
>   Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.

What am I missing here?

// EDIT: I am using ANT in Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

`trycatch` is a task provided by the [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) third-party library. Make sure to download their Jar and have it referenced on the Ant classpath. See [this link](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/#install) for how to do this.

On Eclipse, go to **Window -> Preferences -> Ant -> Runtime**. Under the **Classpath** tab, add the Ant-Contrib jar using the "Add External JARs..." button. And as mentioned in the link, you need to declare the tasks as follows:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>
```

Comment: I am using ANt in eclipse. How should I setup this?

Comment: The taskdef definition using antcontrib.properties is wrong. The antcontrib.properties contains only taskdefs for ant < 1.6, declare it like that (assuming antcontrib.jar already on path) :
  <project xmlns:ac="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib">

    <ac:if>
    ...

or without namespaces :

  <project>

  <!-- Import AntContrib -->
  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>
  ...